# Flask app ignores base url path when deployed via mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have successfully deployed a Flask app via mod_wsgi/apache and can get the base path to render, however none of the links append to the base url, causing a 404 error.

For example:

I expect this: http://hostname.com/script-runner/[flask-route]
But am getting this: http://hostname.com/[flask-route]

Here is my setup:

**Folder structure**

```
script-runner/
├── script_runner.wsgi
├── script_runner.py
└── templates/
```

**script_runner.wsgi**

```
import sys
import logging
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/apps/script-runner')
from script_runner import app as application
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
logging.basicConfig(stream = sys.stderr)
```

**script_runner.conf**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess script-runner user=username group=usernamethreads=5
WSGIProcessGroup script-runner
WSGIScriptAlias /script-runner /usr/local/apps/script-runner/script-runner.wsgi

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/script-runner.*$" script-runner_app
CustomLog /usr/local/apps/script-runner/access.log common env=script-runner_app
```

**Edit**
Adding apache error log of what happens then loading relevant link:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/domain-value, referer: http://10.3.64.250/script-runner
```

So it seems like apache is looking in the wrong directory...?